# Proof that $2^{2017} -1$ is prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm supposed to prove test if $2^{2017}-1$ is prime given that I know the following:

If $p$ is prime then $2^{p-1}=1 \mod p$

I'm pretty much lost on where to begin. I can't prove this directly since I don't know $p$ is prime. I tried doing a proof by contradiction but couldn't get anywhere. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I'm fairly certain I'm not actually supposed to calculate $2^{2^{2017}-1} \mod 2^{2017}-1$ directly in doing this.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you're being asked? (Note that the theorem you quote would not suffice in any case - it is not an if and only if.)

Comment: Note that $2^{p-1}=1\pmod p$ can also hold for some non-primes $p$, for example Carmichael numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number).

Comment: @ArnaudD. I wrote it wrong. I'm being asked to test if it is prime using that theorem.

Comment: According to the table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime it will be precisely 900 years before the corresponding problem will be valid. :)

Answer (score 4):

No, $2^{2017}-1$ is not prime.  One factor is $9338711$. However, it is true that $2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$ where $p = 2^{2017}-1$.

Comment: That was fast ! How did you find this?

Comment: I used Maple:
p:= 2^2017-1;
isprime(p);
ifactor(p, easy);
2 &^(p-1) mod p;

Comment: I wrote the question wrong originally. I'm supposed to test if it is prime using that theorem. By which I assume it means I supposed to use that theorem to demonstrate that it isn't prime, so a computer program doesn't help here.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case that theorem **doesn't** demonstrate that it isn't prime.

Comment: Below that question is a line that says p-2^2017-1; Mod(2,p)^(p-1). That is written in a different font, so I'm thinking its meant to be a bit of code for Sage, which we have used a bit in class. Unfortunately, I don't really understand the connection because that looks like it would do either $(2 \mod p)^{p-1}$ or $(p \mod 2)^{p-1}.

Comment: That should be p = 2^2017-1;
And then Mod(2,p)^(p-1) is the way to compute $2^{p-1} \mod p$, which will return $1$.  That is, Mod(2,p) returns the equivalence class of $2$ modulo $p$, as an element of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.  The $p-1$'th power is computed in that ring, which is what you want.

Comment: But, as I said, the answer is $1$, so this doesn't prove that it isn't prime.  It turns out that for $p = 2^n-1$ where $n$ is prime, you always have $2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$, so Fermat's theorem with base $2$ doesn't help.  On the other hand, computing $3^{p-1} \mod p$ would work in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can edit my comment to fix my mistakes? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: Comments can only be edited for 5 minutes.  After that, AFAIK the only thing you can do is delete it and post a new comment.